# Error función getline

Tags: c++

estoy intentando leer un archivo de texto e imprimir lo que tiene en la pantalla en c++, de momento pude lograrlo con archivos simples de una sola línea pero ahora quiero leer un archivo de texto con espacios y varias columnas. El problema es que está constantemente imprimiendo los datos de la última columna de mi archivo y no se termina nunca.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
typedef char cad100[101];
int main(){
    cad100 cont;
    ifstream paises("Paises25.txt");
    while (!paises.eof()){
        paises >> cont;
        cout << cont << endl;
    }
    paises.close();
return 0;
}
```

Estas son las primeras 3 filas del archivo "Paises25.txt":

Alemania            Europa       82605000
Argentina           América      43823000
Brasil              América     207012000

---

EDIT: Estuve trabajando en otro ejercicio similar y encontré una solución para el problema del bucle infinito y es el "paisesE.clear();" todo se imprime correctamente en la pantalla y ya no se repite una especie de números basura que había, ahora mi pregunta es: ¿Porque funciona? Acá esta el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
typedef char str20[21];
struct sPaises {
    str20 nom,
          cont;
    int hab;
};
bool abrirArchivos(ifstream &archE, sPaises &rPais){
    archE >> rPais.nom;
    archE >> rPais.cont;
    archE >> rPais.hab;
    return archE.good();
}
int main(){
    sPaises rPaises;
    ifstream paisesE("paises.txt");
    cout << paisesE.good() << endl;
    while (abrirArchivos(paisesE, rPaises) == 1){
        paisesE.clear(); // Esta es la linea por la que estoy preguntando.
        cout << rPaises.nom << rPaises.cont << rPaises.hab << endl;
    }
    paisesE.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quieres leer [eso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Comment: Despues de leerlo realmente no llego a entender del todo, entiendo que va a devolver *true* cuando lea el fin del archivo, pero porque importa que no indique que la próxima lectura es el fin del archivo? Cuando lea el fin tendría que parar el ciclo. También intente probando la propia lectura como condición del ciclo y sigue siendo infinito, realmente no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: EOF es una condición cuando intentas leer una línea *y fallas*.  Entonces la secuencia correcta es: intentas leer, verificas, procesas. Pero lo primero que haces es verificar. Qué estas verificando? Aún no has leído nada, ¡nada puede fallar! Intente leer un archivo vacío. ¿Obtiene EOF de inmediato?

Comment: Aaaah gracias por la aclaración, ahora si lo entiendo. Cambié la condición por una de lectura (para ser mas especifico: while (paises>>cont){....}) pero sigo teniendo el bucle infinito y se imprime el ultimo dato de mi archivo de texto.

Comment: Para leer una linéa, usa `std::getline`, no `>>`. También, recomenaría usar std::string.

Comment: Intente usar la función std::getline, pero al compilar me lanza un error "Could not find  a match for 'getline <charT (...)'" in function main(), leyendo la referencia de la función me indica que use un string, entonces mi duda es ¿Existe alguna manera de usar esta función con una cadena de caracteres y no con un string?

Comment: Se puede usar `cin.getine()` en vez de `std::getline`,

Comment: He editado la pregunta, si podrías darle un vistazo para darme una ayuda estaría genial.

Comment: La línea no tiene sentida.  `clear` establesce el estado del `paisesE` en `good`. Pero dentro del bucle tu `paisesE` ya está `good`, de lo contrario, el código no entraría en el bucle. Entonces, la línea no hace nada. Puedes eliminarla.

Comment: Cuando la elimino vuelvo otra vez a un bucle infinito, y por lo que puedo observar, esta imprimiendo números sin sentido que parecen ser basura.Esto es lo que sale en la consola: 1
AlemaniaEuropa82605000
ArgentinaAm├®rica43823000
BrasilAm├®rica207012000
Canad├íAm├®rica36477000
ChinaAsia1380996000
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537
1703537 (...) y sigue imprimiendo

Comment: "Cuando la elimino vuelvo otra vez a un bucle infinito" No puedo reproducir eso. En mi opinión es imposible. ¿Puedes publicar el archivo completo?

Answer (score 0):

El motivo es que la última lectura, la que da con el EOF, se imprime también. Para solucionar esto sólo tienes que hacer una lectura adelantada, modificando el bucle de esta forma:

```cpp
paises >> cont;
while (!paises.eof()){
    cout << cont << endl;
    paises >> cont;
}
```

Comment: Hola, hice la modificación que me sugeriste y sigue estando en un bucle infinito.

Comment: Prueba entonces cambiando la condición de `!paises.eof()` a `paises,good()`. Esto comprueba algunas condiciones adicionales, que podrían ser las que están dando problemas en tu caso concreto. Con las líneas de ejemplo que has puesto en la pregunta me ha funcionado... (aunque he tenido que cambiar `stdio.h` por `iostream`).